# How to have a private Crude application in Laravel (Shows inputs created by specific user)

Tags: laravel, crud

I am trying to create a job board, I am using Crud application for the cv part of the portal, i don want everyone to see other user's cvs.

So the user inputs his data, then only sees his data to apply, edit, show etc. A possible way is to add a created by, but I am not sure if it is the best option.

Users migration
<?php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(1);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

cv migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCvTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('cv', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->index('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string ('FName');
            $table->string ('Nationality');
            $table->string ('Residence');
            $table->string ('email');
            $table->string ('Phone');
            $table->string('DOB');
            $table->string ('Gender');
            $table->string ('EmploymentStatus');
            $table->string ('EducationLevel');
            $table->string ('MajorField');
            $table->string ('Major');
            $table->string ('university');
            $table->string ('GradCounrty');
            $table->string ('GPA');
            $table->string ('ProfCertifications');
            $table->string ('PrevJobTitle');
            $table->date('PrevJobStart');
            $table->date('PrefJobEnd');
            $table->integer('WorkExp'); 
            $table->string('fileCV');
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('trash')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }
 
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('cv');
    }
}
```

CV controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\cv;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class cvController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    function __construct()
    {
         $this->middleware('permission:cv-list|cv-create|cv-edit|cv-delete', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
         $this->middleware('permission:cv-create', ['only' => ['create', 'store']]);
         $this->middleware('permission:cv-edit', ['only' => ['edit', 'update']]);
         $this->middleware('permission:cv-delete', ['only' => ['destroy']]);
    }


    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $data = cv::all();

        return view('cv.index',compact('data'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('cv.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            
            'FName' => 'required',
            
        ]);

        
        $input = $request->all();
        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $imageDestinationPath = 'uploads/images/sliders';
            $postImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($imageDestinationPath, $postImage);
            $input['image'] = "$postImage";
        }
    
    
        cv::create($input);
    
        return redirect()->route('cv.index')
            ->with('success','CV Upladed successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $cv = cv::find($id);

        return view('cv.show', compact('cv')); 
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {

        $cv = cv::find($id);

        return view('cv.edit',compact('cv'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        
        $cv = cv::find($id);
        $this->validate($request, [
            
            'FName' => 'required',
    
        
        ]);

        $input=$request->all();
        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $imageDestinationPath = 'uploads/images/sliders';
            $postImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($imageDestinationPath, $postImage);
            //dd($path);
            $input['image'] = "$postImage";
        }
        else{
            unset($input['image']);
        }
        $cv->update($input);
    
    
        return redirect()->route('cv.index')
            ->with('success', 'CV updated successfully.');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        cv::find($id)->delete();
    
        return redirect()->route('cv.index')
            ->with('success', 'CV deleted successfully.');
    }

    public $gender = [
        "0" => "Female",
        "1" => "Male",
    ];
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add where clause to the index function

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $data = cv::where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->get();
    return view('cv.index', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use **authentication** you can retrieve info of each user by his `token` so you can get only his CVs by the `id_user`

this is the example without token

```
    public function example(Request $request)
{
    $data = cv::where('user_id', $request->user()->id)->get();
    return view('cv.index', compact('data'));
}
```

this is the example with token and **authentication**

```
    public function example()
{
    $data = cv::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
    return view('cv.index', compact('data'));
}
```